# Revert couchdb database file after accidentally switching source and target servers

Tags: couchdb

I wanted to replicate the data from one CouchDB server (*source*) to another one (*target*) but I got careless and switched them during the process using Futon e.g the *source* became the *target* . As a result I lost all the data in my *source* DB file, because the *target* DB was empty and was copied over it. As far as I can see, the replication process has replaced the *source* DB file entirely. If I don't have a backup, is there a way to recover the old DB content on the *source* server?

Thanks in advance.